# Odoo 8 - What is the difference between t-call and xpath

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, qweb

I cant understand what is the difference between the xpath with inside position method and make a t-call in a t element and later add some code inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> xpath is used to make the view of odoo backend.
>   t-call is used to make the view of odoo fronend.

Now if you add an element with XPath & position inside that updated view effect will be shown when its parent view is getting loaded.

With qweb t-call the view you are calling will not change & will not show your changed effect if you call the main template on any page, to see your changes you must use template id in which you are are using t-call & making changes.

Comment: Thanks friend, that has been very helpful